# PHP Unserialize segmentation fault

Tags: php, serialization

When I try to unserialize a large data(7700 KB) using unserialize from php apache give segmentation fault and in browser console I get this error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.How can I do to find out which part of that data is caused the segmentation fault or how can I do to avoid segmentation fault.
Thank you!

Comment: 7 mb of serialized data?

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: Yes 7 mb of serialized data.PHP 5.5

Answer (score 0):

It could be a PHP bug where unserialize cause segmentation fault: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65591

Try to use http://3v4l.org to test unserialization with your data.